# How to create simple Dialog boxes in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.ios, messagebox

Just started dealing with Xamarin iOS (porting monogame app from WP8.1 to iOS) and can't find Message Box, Query BOx, Query text Box, Progress / Wait controls. 
In windows/wp I use XAML page, but it looks like there is not XAML support in Xamarin.iOS.

I saw how to do this using page from xamarin.forms, but I can't believe that such simple things are not implemeneted simply, without storyboards UIView controllers, etc. Besides I can't understand where are pages in my app - it has only Program.cs and Game1.cs files.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/

Comment: How would you do this 'simply'? "...abstraction for the user interface that will be rendered using native controls on iOS, Android, Windows, or Windows Phone..."

Comment: I've found simple way: UIAlertView

Comment: But xna.Guide was much faster, I was searching for something like  async/await getMsgBoxResult(...).